# XGboost custom objective. Gradient & hessian problem

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I am trying to create my `'objective'` = original `'objective': 'reg:squarederror'`.

The model results on my `'objective'` and on the original `'objective': 'reg:squarederror'` are very different.

Why? Where did I go wrong?

```
def my_squarederror(y_pred, y_true):
    grad = 2*(y_pred - y_true)
    hess = 0*y_true + 2
    return grad, hess

XGB_default_mse = xgboost.XGBRegressor().set_params(**{'objective': 'reg:squarederror'}) # original
XGB_my_mse = xgboost.XGBRegressor().set_params(**{'objective': my_squrederror}) # my
```

Comment: it looks good, though did you try to change the sign of the grad? Not that it should be changed, but could be worth to try. also, how much different the results are? and did you fix the seed?

Comment: @Rafa seed is fixed. Change the sign of the grad make results correct! Thank yoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_squarederror(y_pred, y_true):
    grad = 2*(y_pred - y_true)
    hess = 0*y_true + 2
    return -grad, hess
```